# How to understand that minors are matrix elements in fundamental representations of $SL_n$?

Tags: representation-theory, lie-groups, cluster-algebra

In [the video](http://qgm.au.dk/video/mc/cluster/), Lecture 3 of June 14, 49:00-53:00, it is said that "minors are matrix elements in fundamental representations of $SL_n$". What are fundamental representations of $SL_n$? How to understand that minors are matrix elements in fundamental representations of $SL_n$? Thank you very much.

Comment: There are five Lectures 3.

Comment: @joriki, thank you very much. I have edited the post.

Comment: It seems that that video player (at least in my browser) doesn't support seeking. If so, that means you're effectively asking everyone who tries to answer this question to download $322$ MB of video. I think your chances of getting an answer will rise considerably if you either describe what goes on in the lecture or provide an excerpt or some other way of watching those four minutes without downloading the rest. From the perspective of self-containedness of the site, the first option would obviously be preferable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The notion of fundamental representations is defined for any finite-dimensional semisimple Lie algebra ${\mathfrak g}$ with a fixed choice of a Cartan subalgebra ${\mathfrak h}$ and a set of positive roots $\Phi^+\subset\Phi({\mathfrak g},{\mathfrak h})\subset{\mathfrak h}^{\ast}$ of ${\mathfrak g}$ with respect to ${\mathfrak h}$: Namely, if $\{\alpha_1,...,\alpha_n\}$ is an enumeration of the simple roots corresponding to $\Phi^+$, and if $\alpha_1^{\vee},\ldots,\alpha_n^{\vee}$ are the associated coroots in ${\mathfrak h}$, then the *$i$-th fundamental weight* ${\mathfrak g}$ is the unique $\omega_i\in{\mathfrak h}^{\ast}$ such that $\omega_i(\alpha_j^{\vee})=\delta_{ij}$. The *$i$-th fundamental representation* is the unique irreducible representation with highest weight $\omega_i$.

Consider now the case of ${\mathfrak g} = {\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_n({\mathbb C})$ with ${\mathfrak h} := \text{diag}$, $\Phi^+ := \{\varepsilon_i - \varepsilon_j\ |\ i<j\}$ (where $\varepsilon_i:{\mathfrak h}=\text{diag}\to{\mathbb C}$ is the projection onto the $i$-th diagonal entry) and $\alpha_i^{\vee} = \text{diag}(0,\ldots,0,1,-1,0,\ldots,0)$. Then the $i$-th fundamental weight $\omega_i$ is given by $\varepsilon_1+\ldots+\varepsilon_i$, and the $i$-th fundamental representation is the natural representation of ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_n({\mathbb C})$ on $\bigwedge^i {\mathbb C}^n$: If $e_1,\ldots,e_n$ is the standard basis of ${\mathbb C}^n$, then the ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_n({\mathbb C})$-module $\bigwedge^i {\mathbb C}^n$ is spanned by the highest weight vector $e_1\wedge\ldots\wedge e_i$, which has weight $\varepsilon_1+\ldots+\varepsilon_i=\omega_i$ since each $e_j$ has weight $\varepsilon_j$ in the natural representation of ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_n({\mathbb C})$ on ${\mathbb C}^n$.

Finally, the matrix coefficients of ${\mathfrak s}{\mathfrak l}_n({\mathfrak C})$ with respect to the basis $\{e_{j_1}\wedge\ldots\wedge e_{j_i}\ |\ j_1<\ldots<j_i\}$ of $\bigwedge^i{\mathbb C}^n$ are precisely the $i$-minors.

Answer (score 0):

For example, in the case of $SL_3$, we have 
$$
V_{\omega_1} = \langle b_{11}, b_{12}, b_{13} \rangle.
$$
is the fundamental module of $SL_3$ with highest weight $\omega_1$. The weight of $b_{11}$ is $\omega_1$. The weight of $b_{12}$ is $-\omega_1 + \omega_2$. The weight of $b_{13}$ is $-\omega_2$.

We have 
$$
V_{\omega_2} = \langle b_{11}b_{22} - b_{12}b_{21}, b_{12}b_{23}-b_{13}b_{22}, b_{11}b_{23}-b_{13}b_{21} \rangle.
$$
The weight of $b_{11}b_{22} - b_{12}b_{21}$ is $\omega_2$.